# Android crashing activity after entering input to AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, autocompletetextview

I'm developing a weather app, i used OpenWeatherMap API. I have a problem with searching cities. There are some city list on OpenWeatherMap website to use your project. I'm using city_list.gz which is approximately 1 MB with gzip. Original file is 4 MB.There are more than 200.000 cities in list . With below code, I add cities to an Arraylist:

```
private void bringData() {
    cityList=new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
        InputStream is= getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.city_list);
        GZIPInputStream gzıpInputStream=new GZIPInputStream(is);

        InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(gzıpInputStream);
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(reader);

        String readed;

        while ((readed=in.readLine())!=null)
            builder.append(readed);
        cityList=new Gson().fromJson(builder.toString(),new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call this method on onCreate. I'm using this Arraylist for AutoCompleteTextView to search cities. Here is my related codes:

```
 etSearchCity=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.etSearchCity);
    etSearchCity.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);

    autoComplete = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cityList);

    etSearchCity.setAdapter(autoComplete);

    etSearchCity.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {

            city=(String) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
            btnSaveCity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvSearch.setText("Do you want add city: "+city);
            tvSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

These codes working properly on Android Emulator on Android Studio, but on my real device activity is crashing with second or third letter of writing on AutoCompleteTextView. I encounter below logs in Logact:

```
I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 45388(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 17(292KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 10MB/11MB, paused 20.543ms total 209.212ms
```

How can i fix that problem. Can i use firebase database for searching? I want suggestion of cities with second or third entry of AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: That log message is not an error.  It's informational (as it starts with the letter "I").

Comment: after crashing all logs are deleted, i can only read that message